# jump to start screen from a windows 8 app on clicking "Go to Start"button (Appbarbutton)

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I am developing a windows 8 store app using c# and XAML. while checking out some standard appbarbuttons in StandardStyles.xaml , i came across to see a button called "Go To Start" . !
!

I don't have idea how to launch start screen by click this button. It would be useful if someone share how to do it .

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to close your app. If that's what you want.

Window.Current.Close();

Answer (score 0):

If your Startscreen is called e.g. MainPage, you can do this with:

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
```

If that's not the answer you want, maybe a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh771188.aspx will help you.